# Why Azure Analysis Services is processing tables sequentially instead of in parallel?

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services, azure-synapse

I have a pretty basic model with just 7 tables all under 100 million records, and upon processing the tables in SSMS, Azure Analysis services(on S4) is loading tables one by one, in sequence, as seen below, instead of in parallel. I am pulling from Synapse Analytics(on DWU1000c), an MPP data warehouse that can definitely handle the data pull.

Is there a setting I am missing to allow these to run all at once in parallel? (In my history of building and supporting models, I have never seen activity such as this)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a limitation of SSMS, as you can achieve this in PowerShell (I am using this in a Azure Automation Runbook);

Many refresh requests for various tables, but for each partition in a table. e.g.
LogMessage("Processing dimension partition {0} in table {1}..." -f $partition.Name, $table.Name)
$table.Partitions[$partition.Name].RequestRefresh([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.RefreshType]::DataOnly)

Followed later by a single call to carry out the requested refreshes;
$database.Update([Microsoft.AnalysisServices.UpdateOptions]::ExpandFull)

Then all the tables are processed in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any setting but one option we used to do is by generating the script in SSMS as below and run it that will do parallel processing.

[image]